# Asp.net webforms application runs painfully slow

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have gotten a custody of a 5 years old application with a strange problem. After application pool has been recycled, first visitor has to suffer through a startup penalty that is usually from 6 to 10 seconds, but can be as much as 120s.

Application itself was a learning platform for many young developers at the company. As this things go, it one day turned into full product and is causing real pain to the customers.

Here is MiniProfiler result of important part to prove it:

```
                                                   duration  with children  from start
http://myapp_test_server/app/Dashboard.aspx             2.1         8390.3        +0.3
  Begin request                                      6921.6         8388.2        +2.4
   Session started                                    405.2         1466.6     +6924.0
```

Application_BeginRequest event handler is empty. So is Session_Start.

Applications web.config has this set and it does nothing:

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" batch="false" optimizeCompilations="true" debug="false" />
```

I have also tried with various settings for all 3 params, but to no avail.

The only thing that did shave couple of seconds off the penalty was using aspnet_compiler after application pool recycle to compile JITted code. Still, it did not remove the problem.

Any ideas why would take application that long to start?

Comment: [precompilation](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/precompiling-your-website-cs) can help.

Comment: I did that. It shaved couple of seconds off the lag, but it still remains unusually high